# SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send() - failing to reconnect

Tags: javascript, signalr

`SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()`

Tried adding the below code into my  `$.connection.hub.disconnected()` method as per the documentation but it's still throwing this error message.

```
        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
        {
            console.log('Wallboards : Connection Disconected');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 5000);

            console.log('Wallboards : Connection Restarted')

        });
```

Any ideas what else may be causing this?